# Is the method removeAndReturnError: not necessary?

Tags: cocoa-touch, icloud, conflict, uidocument, nsfileversion

I've just read the documentation about conflict resolution with UIDocuments in the iCloud:
[Resolving Document Version Conflicts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocumentBasedAppPGiOS/ResolveVersionConflicts/ResolveVersionConflicts.html)

In the last point of the chapter "How to Tell iOS That a Document Version Conflict Is Resolved" is written:

> Remove the resolved versions of the document.
>   For any versions you no longer need, call the removeAndReturnError: method of NSFileVersion to reclaim the storage for the file. Document revisions remain on the server until you delete them.

But in the code sample "Listing 6-3" there is no removeAndReturnError: method called.
Is this method not necessary or where should I call it?

Thanks for any help

Linard